# Unable to stop nginx from redirecting to HTTPS on subdomain

Tags: server, nginx

I'm trying to have a top level domian **www.example.com** which is a wordpress site, and I want it to always force HTTPS, however I also have a subdomain **subdomain.mysite.com** which I want to be HTTP only.

Right now, with my server block set, **subdomain.mysite.com** keeps re-directing into **HTTPS**, in Firefox, and in chrome I get a too many redirects crash.

What is wrong with my file?

Here is my server block file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
 }

server {
  # SSL configuration
  #
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;";

  root /var/www/example.com/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;    
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;     
   }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;    
  }
}


# www.subdomain.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 http://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 http://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  # SSL configuration
  #
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 http://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;  
}

# subdomain.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.example.com;
  root /var/www/subdomain.example.com/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;    

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;";

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;    
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }  

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;     
   }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Edit: These are the headers I get back when trying to access subdomain.example.com

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:lang=en
Host:subdomain.example.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: it's less an NGINX configuration and a side effect of HSTS.  Your browser remembers HSTS capacity for sites (in Firefox and Chrome), so you'd need to nuke your entire browser cache from the beginning to 'forget' the HSTS setting.  As well, redirections are 'cached', and the presence of HSTS kind of forces HTTPS thanks to the HSTS cache.  You'd have to completely remove your Strict-Transport-Security header, *and* prune your browser cache completely.

Comment: Note that even then, you may not be guaranteed to return to the original 'redirection' that you intended.  This is why you don't enable HSTS on a given domain or subdomain without being *absolutely* certain you want to risk the redirection problem.

Comment: @ThomasWard hm I just erased everything form chrome following a guide, and emptied cache, and I'm still getting the same thing. I am not sure how to proceed now and test this. When I inspect the site headers I don't see the HSTS header, and it still redirects me to https.

Comment: note my second comment - what you're observing is what HSTS kind of forces - HTTPS attempts.  You *might* have to delete your entire Google Chrome profile folder, and lose everything you've stored, to forget your HSTS stuff.  The problem is, HSTS can *break* things like this, and there's really not much we can do about that.  It's a failing in HSTS but also one of the *reasons* HSTS exists.  There's no real way around it.

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't think this is correct. I just went to browserling.com and tried my site there, and I still get the too many redirects. I've never been there before with that service, so if my configuration was correct, it should display correctly there, right?

Comment: Not necessarily - I'd need to know more about your site config, as well as your subdomain actually to do testing.  The core problem is we also see Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1 which suggests it's trying to force HTTPS.  That could be due to any number of reasons.  But normalyl, HTTPS -> HTTP redirection doesn't occur at all.  You usually just don't serve anything on HTTPS.

Comment: @ThomasWard so what do you suggest as my next step? I'm kind of lost right now.